# Github API for Python : PyGithub - get a list of all commits for a particular repository

Tags: python, git, version-control, github, repository

I am developing a script which requires me to get a list of all commits for a particular repository, as well as the date and time of commit. The Commit Class in the PyGithub API:

https://github.com/jacquev6/PyGithub/blob/master/doc/ReferenceOfClasses.md#class-commit

does not have any member for date-of-commit and time-of-commit.
Any ideas on how to get the date and time of a commit using the API?

Comment: Is this a question? I don't think so.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to answer, but you can get the information from the [GitAuthor](http://jacquev6.net/PyGithub/v1/github_objects/GitAuthor.html#github.GitAuthor.GitAuthor) of the [GitCommit](http://jacquev6.net/PyGithub/v1/github_objects/GitCommit.html#github.GitCommit.GitCommit) of the Commit.
This will print the dates of all the commits:

```
for commit in commits:
    if commit.commit is not None:
        print commit.commit.author.date
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call

```
commit.getStatuses()
```

and in each satsus there is attributes **created_at** and **updated_at**

from here: https://github.com/jacquev6/PyGithub/blob/master/doc/ReferenceOfClasses.md#class-commitstatus

Class CommitStatus

Attributes:

- created_at: datetime.datetime
- creator: NamedUser
- description: string
- id: integer
- state: string
- target_url: string
- updated_at: datetime.datetime

Comment: I wondered about this, but why would there be more than one `CommitStatus` per commit?

Comment: @wrgrs Isn't that because you may amend commits and push changes again? (or even do a rebase)

Answer (score 0):

```
   from github import Github

   gh = Github(base_url="", login_or_token="")

   repo = gh.get_repo(repo_name)

   #returned commits in a paginated list
   commits = repo.get_commits()
```